# MySQL Run-time error '-2147217865 (80040e37)'

Tags: mysql, vb6, odbc

> Windows 7 (x64), VB6.0 - SP6 and MySQL 5.2 ODBC Connectors and Xammp
>   Server

that works properly on local host Now I am trying to connect with remote MySQL database with same tables but after successful connection it gives me Run-time error '-2147217865 (80040e37)' and says the table **mydatabase.tblusers** doesn't exist but actually its exist in my database.
I searched over the internet for all possible solution but still its not working for me

**Here is my connection string**

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Connected2DB() As Boolean
Dim isOpen      As Boolean
Dim ANS         As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim dbpath As String

    isOpen = False
    On Error GoTo err

    Do Until isOpen = True
      CN.CursorLocation = adUseClient
      CN.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL;Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};DSN=myDSN;Server=MyIPAddress;Database=myDatabase;Uid=DBUserName;Pwd=mypassword;Port=3306;"
      CN.Open
      isOpen = True
    Loop
    Connected2DB = isOpen
    Exit Function
err:
    ANS = MsgBox("Error Number: " & err.Number & vbCrLf & "Description: " & err.Description, _
  vbCritical + vbRetryCancel)
  If ANS = vbCancel Then
    Connected2DB = False
  ElseIf ANS = vbRetry Then
    Connected2DB = vbRetry
  End If
End Function

Public Sub CloseDB()
    'Close the connection
    CN.Close
    Set CN = Nothing
End Sub
```

and here is my code

```
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()
Dim strPass As String

If txtUsername.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox "Username and/or Password is incorrect.Try Again!", vbExclamation
    txtUsername.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

If txtPassword.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox "Username and/or Password is incorrect.Try Again!", vbExclamation
    txtPassword.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

strPass = Encode(txtPassword.Text)
'strPass = txtPassword.Text

Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset
'If RS.State = adStateOpen Then RS.Close
RS.Open "SELECT tblUsers.* FROM tblUsers WHERE Username='" & txtUsername.Text & "' AND Password ='" & strPass & "' AND StatusCD ='ACTIVE'", CN, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
If RS.RecordCount < 1 Then
    Attempt = Attempt - 1
    MsgBox "Username and/or Password is incorrect.Try Again!", vbExclamation
    lblAttempt.Caption = "Remaining Attempt(s): " & Attempt

    If Attempt = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You have reached maximum login attempts. System will now be terminated!", vbExclamation

        MDIMain.CloseMe = True
        END_APP = True
        Unload Me
    End If
Else
    LOGIN_SUCCEEDED = True

    ACTIVE_USER.USERID = RS.Fields("UserCD")
    ACTIVE_USER.FULLNAME = RS.Fields("Fullname")
    ACTIVE_USER.USERNAME = RS.Fields("Username")
    ACTIVE_USER.PASSCODE = RS.Fields("Password")
    ACTIVE_USER.USER_ISADMIN = CBool(changeYNValue(getValueAt("SELECT Username,IsAdmin FROM tblUsers WHERE Username='" & txtUsername.Text & "'", "IsAdmin")))

    blnCreate = CBool(changeYNValue(RS.Fields("ModCreate")))
    blnUpdate = CBool(changeYNValue(RS.Fields("ModUpdate")))
    blnDelete = CBool(changeYNValue(RS.Fields("ModDelete")))

    'InsertLogs Name, "Action Taken: Logged in to the Program", "Executed:" & Time

    MDIMain.lblCurrentUser.Caption = ACTIVE_USER.FULLNAME
    MDIMain.lblDate.Caption = Now() 'Format(Now, "MMMM dd, yyyy")

    Unload Me
    MDIMain.Show
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote server permissions accept table names (case sensitive) double check for your tables names on remote server then in your code. Issue resolved by renaming MySQL statements of all relevant tables